# Stop HTML DOM elements duplicating on form re-submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a login form with a custom alert that shows when the users inputs invalid data into the input box. However, I have encountered an issue. Whenever the user clicks on the "Register" button, my Javascript code duplicates the elements instead of only creating the element once (which is what I want).

This therefore means that the user can "spam click" the button and create a endless amount of Javascript-generated HTML elements. This is obviously an issue. I have tried using boolean values to stop the function running after the first run:

```
var executed = false;
if (!executed) {
   executed = true;
   continue;
}
```

However that **doesn't seem to work**. I Have also tried wrapping the code with

```
setTimeout(function(){
//my code here
}, 5000);
```

and that also **doesn't seem to work** and just refreshes the page onclick.

So my question is,

how can I only make the element **once** when the function is called and stop duplicating the elements on form resubmission?

I'm using XAMPP as my test server if that means anything.

```js
//validate form
function validateForm() {
  //validate email
  document.getElementById("formError").style.display = 'block';
  var title = document.createElement("h2");
  var titleText = document.createTextNode("Fix these issues:");
  title.appendChild(titleText);
  var errorTitle = document.getElementById("errorTitle");
  errorTitle.classList.add("errorTitle");
  errorTitle.appendChild(title);

  var email = form["email"].value;

  if (email === "") {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var paraText = document.createTextNode("* Email must not be left blank.");
    para.appendChild(paraText);
    var errorParagraph = document.getElementById("errorParagraph");
    errorParagraph.classList.add("errorParagraph");
    errorParagraph.appendChild(para);

    //validate code
    var code = form["code"].value;

    if (code === "") {
      var para = document.createElement("p");
      var paraText = document.createTextNode("* Invite code must not be left blank.");
      para.appendChild(paraText);
      var errorParagraph = document.getElementById("errorParagraph");
      errorParagraph.classList.add("errorParagraph");
      errorParagraph.appendChild(para);

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#formError').fadeOut('slow');
      }, 5000);
    }
  return false;
  }
}

var form = document.getElementById("loginForm");
form.onsubmit = validateForm;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--div for form errors-->
<div id='container'>
  <div class='formError' id='formError'>
    <h1 id='errorTitle'></h1>
    <p id='errorParagraph'></p>
  </div>
</div>

<!--login form-->
<form id='loginForm' action='#' method='post'>
  <h1 class='formTitle formText'>T O E A I M</h1>
  <p class='formParagraph formText'>Purchase CS:GO Cheats and more!</p>

  <div class='inputForm'>
    <label class='formLabel'>
          <input type='email' placeholder='Enter your Email Address' name='email' autocomplete='off'>
        </label>
    <label class='formLabel'>
          <input type='password' placeholder='Enter your Invite Code' name='code' autocomplete='off'>
        </label>
    <button type='submit' class='formBtn'>Register</button><br>
    <span class='noLogin'><a href='#' class='noLoginText'>Don't have a code?</a> or <a href='#' class='noLoginText'>Already have an account?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show and hide error divs instead of creating new ones

Comment: Also Ps should not be nested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add to the DOM if you can just toggle existing HTML

Alternatively just add required to the email field and code field

```js
$(function() {
  $("#loginForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    var email = $(this).find("[name=email]").val();
    var invite = $(this).find("[name=code]").val();

    $("#emailError").toggle($.trim(email) === "");
    $("#inviteError").toggle($.trim(invite) === "")
    if ($("#emailError").is(":visible") ||
      $("#inviteError").is(":visible")) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.formError').fadeOut('slow');
      }, 5000);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.formError {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--div for form errors-->
<div id='container'>
  <div class='formError' id='emailError'>
    <h1>* Email must not be left blank.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='formError' id='inviteError'>
    <h1>* Invite code must not be left blank.</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!--login form-->
<form id='loginForm' action='#' method='post'>
  <h1 class='formTitle formText'>T O E A I M</h1>
  <p class='formParagraph formText'>Purchase CS:GO Cheats and more!</p>

  <div class='inputForm'>
    <label class='formLabel'>
          <input type='email' placeholder='Enter your Email Address' name='email' autocomplete='off'>
        </label>
    <label class='formLabel'>
          <input type='password' placeholder='Enter your Invite Code' name='code' autocomplete='off'>
        </label>
    <button type='submit' class='formBtn'>Register</button><br>
    <span class='noLogin'><a href='#' class='noLoginText'>Don't have a code?</a> or <a href='#' class='noLoginText'>Already have an account?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>
```